# Jupyter lab widgets not exporting to HTML

Tags: widget, jupyter, jupyter-lab, export-to-html

I have a problem with widgets' visualization and export in Jupyter lab. Basically, some widgets (e.g. the text) show their output in the log rather than in the console (see the image below).

[image: first screenshot]

Moreover, when I try to export them in HTML they don't appear at all (see the second image below).

[image: second screenshot]

I'm using the following versions:

- Python: 3.7.7;
- Jupyter Lab: 1.2.6;
- Jupyter Notebook: 6.0.3;
- Jupyter core: 4.6.3;
- Ipywidgets: 7.5.1;
- Lab-manager: 1.1.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Do this through [Voilà](https://voila.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html)

```
pip install voila
```

or

```
conda install voila -c conda-forge
```

And then:

```
voila path/to/your/notebook.ipynb
```

For more information and example:

[And Voilà!](https://blog.jupyter.org/and-voil%C3%A0-f6a2c08a4a93)

[Creating an Interactive Dashboard from Jupyter Notebook with Voila](https://towardsdatascience.com/creating-an-interactive-dashboard-from-jupyter-notebook-with-voila-b64918b4d15a)